# NodeJS V8 heap statistics remain the same

Tags: node.js

I'm tracking some of the NodeJS stats and found a really interesting result on the validity of the stats returned. If I check either these functions in the NodeJS REPL.

```
require('v8').getHeapStatistics()

node -p "require('v8').getHeapStatistics()"
```

I get the expected results and as expected they vary all the time, but when I run them as a script using the -p or e flag, they weirdly return the same result no matter how many times I execute it. Am I missing something really obvious about the way NodeJS handle running scripts?